# How to use qiskit gpu on window?

Tags: python, qiskit

I want to calculate unitary of quantum circuit with GPU because my cpu is already too busy.
But it seems qiskit-aer-gpu supports only ubuntu. Is there any way to use it on window10?

Answer (score 1):

The **qiskit-aer-gpu** package provided is only available on Linux running on a x86_64 platform. If you want to make it run on Windows, you'll have to build the Aer code to support GPU from source. You can refer [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-with-gpu-support) for instructions.

Another way might be to use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to install CUDA and use the already built **qiskit-aer-gpu** package.  I've never tried it but it's worth a try. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Patrick